# Magento order confirmation email by payment method

Tags: magento

I add CMS Block (cheque) to checkout success (success.phtml) in my theme
This will show CMS block if will be payment Cheque/Money Order.

But I would like same in confirmation email if payment will be PayPal show original if will be cheque add CMS block to body.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to follow the following steps:

1. From `System` >> `Transactional Emails`, add new template for Order email.

   ```
   {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/paymentcontent.phtml' order=$order}}
   ```

   Add the above block on desired location in the email content where you want to show the static block content.
2. Assign the newly created order email template from `System` >> `Configuration` >> `Sales Emails`.
3. In you current theme create the file `email/order/paymentcontent.phtml` and add the following content:

   ```
   <?php 
     $order = $this->getOrder();
     $paymentcode = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
      if($paymentcode == 'checkmo') {
   ?>
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer_links')->toHtml() ?>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

Here you can change Static block Id as per your requirement